# Android scrollview with imageview not working

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I have a scroll view and an image view. it looks like this:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/theImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </ScrollView>
```

and I setting the image background dynamically like so:
Bitmap bmp;

```
String fileName = Utils.PATH + "/" + getIntent().getStringExtra(Utils.FILE_NAME_ON_INTENT);
bmp = Utils.decodeFile(this, fileName);
theImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

so I see theimage inside the scrollview, but it is not scrolling for some reason.
and if I put the image background like so:

```
int img = R.drawable.some_image;
        theImage.setImageResource(img);
```

Then it is working. but I did this just for a test, all my images are not in the drawable and I dont know how to get the images from the drawable in a dynamic way.

so is there a way to make it scroll with the set as bitmap wap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView) as your scroll view. Secondly try this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/theImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it says that nestedscrollview isn't allowed there. it's inside a `DrawerLayout` if it matter

Comment: @TheWallpaperWorld have you tried placing `NestedScrollView` inside a view group like relative or frame layout?

Comment: great it works! but I have now another question, is there a way to resize the image view? now the `scale type` is `center crop` and the picture is still very big. is there a way to make it in the activity layout to be only 50% of it's size?

Comment: Have you played around with other `scaleType` options, like `center` or `centerInside` to see if it's what you need?

Comment: I want it to be something like: `layout_width=80%` so it would be `80%` of screen size. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, one of the options is using [Percent support library](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en) which is deprecated and not recommended but another option is to use a linear layout with a `layout_weightSum` of 10 and a child with `layout_weight` of 8, which makes it 80 percent height of the layout. Don't forget to put `android:orientation="vertical"` for the linear layout to make it consider 80% as the **height** value.

Comment: If you need more instructions on the second option, ask another question and paste its link here for me to answer it.